# Why aren't google chrome extensions auto updating?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I developed a Google Chrome extension and published from Google Chrome Developer Dashboard. After a month, I updated the newer version of my plugin to the webstore using Developer Dashboard but it is not auto updating to my users. Even after a week.

I haven't implemented anything for auto updates.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate

I read this article, they mentioned "If you publish using the Chrome Developer Dashboard, you can ignore this page".

Why is auto update not working?

Answer (score 1):

- It's possible that they use a slower internet connection, and if the extension is a big file. It need more time to download this.
- Or you request a minimum Google Chrome version, and that users doesn't have this version. So it stay on the old Chrome extension version.